# Subscriber stats tool in google webmaster tools has no data

Tags: google-search-console

In Google webmaster tools under Subscriber stats, it is always in the state: No data available. (Why not?) I want to ask it to do? google and how to display data for that tool

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your site is the one listed in your profile, it's because you don't have an RSS or Atom feed on your site, so there's nothing that people can subscribe to.

Comment: Does it count subscribers or google reader-only subscribers?  I thought it was the latter.

Comment: "Subscriber stats display the number of Google users who have subscribed to your feeds using any Google product (such as Reader, iGoogle, or Orkut). " https://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=73026&hl=en

Comment: Google also owns feedburner, so it might be worth setting your site up in feedburner to try to kick start the stats.

Answer (score 0):

How new is your site? It may take a while for a new site to get spidered, indexed and receive search traffic. By a while I mean it may take months.

Do you have links pointing to your site from other sites. aka backlinks. Without links from other web sites the google spider will find you difficult to find and might not index you if it does find. Try to ask some similar sites to link to you or ask some friends to do so.

Create a sitemap.xml file for your site and submit it via the google webmaster tools. This makes it easer for google to index your site.

Comment: The OP is asking specifically about subscriber (feed) stats - nothing to do with indexing stats.